# Flakey connection to dev machine

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, local-network

My app calls to my dev machine over the local network to get some data. Usually this work fine, but sometimes it won't connect and times out. When this happens, I can copy and paste from the output window the URL its requested and paste it into a browser on a different system, and the request works fine.

After a while, the app will connect fine without any changes on my part.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might happen?

Sometimes, I get this message to the output window...

```
> 2017-01-19 16:35:28.427179 MyApp[489:69535] [] nw_socket_connect
> connectx failed: [64] Host is down 2017-01-19 16:35:28.817530
> MyApp[489:69426] PromiseKit: unhandled error: Error
> Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."
> UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1702428b0 {Error
> Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)"
> UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=64, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.8.52:45455/api/hello,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.8.52:45455/api/hello,
> _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=64, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.}
```